# endless running vertical cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, infinite-scroll, vertical-scrolling

Follow question/answers here, I'm able to create an infinite vertical scroll already, but just for one background image.
Now I move to a new problem.
I have multi background frame image, like 7 frames to complete a background scroll animation.
I can run animation as an endless animation aswell just follow this:

```
-(void)scrollBackground:(ccTime)dt
{
    timeWaited+=dt;
    if (timeWaited<FRAME_RATE) {
        return;
    }
    timeWaited = 0;
    bgIndex++;
    if (bgIndex == 7) {
       bgIndex = 0;
    }
    CCSprite* bgSprite = bgSprites[bgIndex];
    bgSprite.zOrder = LAYER_BACKGROUND;
}
```

But it look very jerky and actually dont look like it's running forward, 
I think i may need to scroll each sprite a little before replace it with new sprite,
Or may be i need to zoom each sprite a bit to fit new sprite

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897229/how-to-move-background-images-infinitely-in-ios-coco2d

Comment: I just added an answer to the referenced question. While it is about horizontal scrolling, it is very easy to apply the idea to this problem.